# Excel formula to split text

Tags: excel

I have an `Excel sheet` like as per the below image.

[image]

From this `Excel sheet` I want to extract data like

[image]

I used Excel formula like `LEFT(D3,FIND("-",D3)-1)`. 
I also know `SUBSTITUTE` function to remove specific data like  `SUBSTITUTE(F3,".jar","")`.

I am not able to implement all of this at a time as I am completely new to do all this in Excel. Is there any way to do this?

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You;re right on the mark with Left & Substitute. Just add on a bit of creativity. If we can assume that version is displayed after the final "-" and extension is after the final ".", we use use place holder characters to track the final "-" & "." of each File Detail.

Assume Assuming FileDetails are in Cell A2, you can input the below formula for FileName & Version in

```
Cell B2:

=LEFT(A2,SEARCH("!@#@!",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","!@#@!",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""))))-1)

Cell C2:

=MID(A2,SEARCH("!@#@!",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","!@#@!",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""))))+1,SEARCH("#@!",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","#@!",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",""))))-(SEARCH("!@#@!",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","!@#@!",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""))))+1))

Placeholder for final "-": !@#@!

Placeholder for final ".": #@!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+--+
|    File Details     |                        Find                         |  Artifact name  |            version            |  |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+--+
| activation-1.1.jar  | =MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2&"0123456789")) | =MID(A2,1,B2-2) | =MID(A2,B2,LEN(A2)-LEN(C2)-5) |  |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+--+